# Error while running Appium script to start Calculator application

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am new to Appium and just started with my first test script to start calculator app. I am using Appium version 1.17.0 and Java version 8. 
Below is my code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class AppTest1 
{

    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;


      public static void main(String[] args) {

      try 
      { 
          openCalculator();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      { // TODO Auto-generated catch
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
      }

    public static void openCalculator() throws Exception
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy M30S");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "RZ8N10BC9CT");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.calculator");
        cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
        System.out.println("My First Appium Test script for Calculator is running..");
    }

}
```

And I am getting this error: Please help as I am trying different google solutions but nothing is working out and stuck in this since last 5 days :(

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-TN4V3G6', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
[Logcat](https://github.com/Dishita2612/Logs) is uploaded here.
Detailed log file [AppiumTestscript Error](https://github.com/Dishita2612/Logs).doc is uploaded here

Comment: deviceName is the name that appears when you run ./adb devices in platform-tools, i think the deviceName you are using is wrong, also check  that the appPackage and appActivity is correct, it has to be the main app activity
also change  static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver; for public AndroidDriver without the static word and without appium

Comment: Thanks Adrian for response, I tried the changes as mentioned by you but no luck :( Its still throwing same error.

Comment: try to run the script without uuid and platformVersion. Please attach the full appium server log. Make sure your appium server is running